# How to get values in URL apart from the base URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have URLs like this `https://somedomain.com/users/countries?q="value"`. and `https://somedomain.com/users/portal?q="value"`  I am trying to always get `users/countries` or `user/portal` from the URL in javascript.

How do i do this ?

All other solutions are only showing how to get the query params which is not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [URL Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```js
const rawUrl = 'https://somedomain.com/users/countries?q="value"'
const url = new URL(a);
console.log(url)
/*
{
  hash: ""
  host: "somedomain.com"
  hostname: "somedomain.com"
  href: "https://somedomain.com/users/countries?q=%22value%22"
  origin: "https://somedomain.com"
  password: ""
  pathname: "/users/countries"
  port: ""
  protocol: "https:"
  search: "?q=%22value%22"
  searchParams: {}
  username: ""
}
*/
```

Or if you want to access current url path just use

```js
window.location.pathname
```